# Maven 3.0.5 and IntelliJ 12 building two jar files

Tags: java, jar, intellij-idea, maven-3

I am using Maven 3.0.5 with IntelliJ 12 and my pom file is set to build a jar with dependencies. Now that works great but my question is this. How do I tell the pom file to only build one jar? Right now I am getting one jar with dependencies which is want I am after but I also get another jar without dependencies which I end up just deleting by hand. I check here: http://maven.apache.org/pom.html and it looks like packaging will default to building a jar even if I don't specify it and in my  section of the pom I am telling Maven to build another jar file. What can I change in my pom to build only one jar with dependencies?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.xyz.program.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>xyz-program-test</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.2</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.31.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
            <version>2.31.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
            <version>2.31.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
                <version>2.31.0</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                        <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.setup.test.Setup</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Apologies for the formatting.

Comment: Does your root project has the following configuration `<packaging>jar</packaging>`? If so, change it to `<packaging>pom</packaging>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written in the [pom reference page](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html) you're linking to:

> Aggregation (or Multi-Module)
>
> A project with modules is known as a multimodule, or aggregator project. Modules are projects that this POM lists, and are executed as a group. An pom packaged project may aggregate the build of a set of projects by listing them as modules, which are relative directories to those projects.

In order to have a "pom packaged project" mark your root project as such - notice the `pom` in packaging:

```
<groupId>com.xyz.program.test</groupId>
<artifactId>xyz-program-test</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
```